# Consequences of overloading the conversion operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a class with an overloaded conversion operator like this:

```
template <class T> class Pointer {
    T* object;
public:
    Pointer (T* object): object(object) {}
    operator T* () { return object; }
};
```

I noticed that some operators that I would normally have to manually overload now suddenly work as if `Pointer` were a `T*` but some operators don't:

```
MyClass my_object;
Pointer<MyClass> pointer (&my_object);
if (pointer) { /* ... */ } // works
if (pointer == &my_object) { /* ... */ } // works
(*pointer).some_method (); // works
pointer->some_method (); // doesn't work
pointer = pointer + 1; // works
pointer++; // doesn't work
```

Assuming this is correct behaviour according to the standard, how do I know what works and what doesn't (without trial and error) and more importantly, why is it that way?

Comment: Incidentally, making the constructor `explicit` would cause `pointer = pointer + 1;` to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of above operations work because compiler can convert custom type: `Pointer<MyClass>` to raw pointer: `MyClass*` implicitly using SINGLE user-defined conversion.
There are strict rules for implicit conversions, described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type
>   T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some
>   other type T2, in particular:
>
> ```
> (1) When the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with T2 as parameter.
> (2) When the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2
> (3) When initializing a new object of type T2, including return statement in a function returning T2.
> (4) When the expression is used in a switch statement (T2 is integral type)
> (5) When the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (T2 is bool)
> ```

Some investigation with above example, I'll be grateful if someone could verify or correct my deductions.

- case (5), `if` statement:

  `if (pointer) { /* ... */ } // works`
- case (2), `operator==` with operand which can be implicitly converted to `MyClass*`:

  `if (pointer == &my_object) { /* ... */ } // works`
- case (2), indirection (`operator*`) taking operand which can be implicitly converted to `MyClass*`, then structure reference (`operator.`):

  `(*pointer).some_method (); // works`
- does not match any of cases, `operator->` does not take any argument(s), which can be implicitly converted:

  `pointer->some_method (); // doesn't work`
- case (2): `operator+` taking operand which can be implicitly converted to `MyClass*` and assign return value to `Pointer<MyClass>` using constructor and `operator=`; note that adding `explicit` to constructor prevents from compiling because return type of expression: `pointer + 1` is `MyClass*`, so constructor taking `MyClass*` is implicitly called:

  `pointer = pointer + 1; // works`
- does not match any of cases; note that even explicit convertion to `MyClass*` (ex. `static_cast<MyClass*>(pointer)++`) won't help, because lvalue is needed here; the workaround is: `auto ptr = &(*pointer); ptr++;`:

  `pointer++; // doesn't work`

Remember, that overloading the conversion operator could sometimes lead to dangerous situations, ex. `MyClass* ptr = pointer; delete ptr;` will delete underlying resource and compiler won't even complain.

Comment: why does `pointer->some_method ();` need more than one implicit conversion? `pointer` can be converted to `T*` and that should be enough to make the operator work

Comment: Adding `operator->` to `Pointer` class helps: `T* operator->() { return object; }`